# Test package-specific logic in yet unpackaged code

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, packagelicense

**We need to use package-specific logic like:**

1. Getting the number of Package Licenses (`PackageLicense`) available in the org

This value can be only obtained after packaging the app and installing it on org.

**What is the best way to go through testing with this kind of logic?**

Right now we are thinking about using 2 scopes, when in packaged scope (namespace exists) use the proper logic, for all other testing envs (no namespace) just use some mocked value.

Comment: The solution I always choose is to provide mocking of the underlying context, such as in this case the package license query. This can most easily be achieved by adopting design patterns like the [fflib selector pattern](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_apply_selector_l_principles) though there are more ad-hoc and light weight approaches. Essentially, your unit test will call the code that decides what to do in various scenarios based on licensing, and that code will use a mocked version of the selector to get the license detail.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you **not** use access to the namespace as a switch between behaviours; this may well shoot you in the foot as and when you look to adopt scratch org, sfdx-based development practices.

Comment: Worth also remembering that your unit tests are actually always executed **OUTSIDE** the context of the package, before the package version is created.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW. You are right about "shooting in the foot" in case of using scratch-orgs. I will consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking it would be the way to go and you should definitely use it if you can. Otherwise, a fallback is using the oft-hated `Test.isRunningTest()`. It gets a bad rap because you shouldn't be modifying your code for tests, but in the world of ISVs I find there's just some areas where you can't replicate a prod instance in any kind of sensible fashion.

Given this is something rather benign (getting the license count), I'd go with using it to just return a value so you can at least test all the logic around it. Sometimes there are better workarounds, and I'm sure some people will hate this answer, but I'm sure you have other things to work on that make better use of your time.

Comment: Thanks! At the end we will try to incorporate mocking, in case we will not have enough time `Test.isRunningTest()` would be ok solution.

Comment: We have old code with `Test.isRunningTest` but all our new code uses mocking. The use of this method is, IMHO, often done to expedite testing of poorly structured code that does not allow mocking. It is not generally necessary (I won't say never, just in case, but we have not found the need).